# (X, T) is an indiscrete space and A a subset of X with at least two elements. Show that every point of X is a limit point of A.

Tags: general-topology

I read an example from "Topology Without Tears".

Let $(X,\tau)$ be an indiscrete space and $A$ a subset of $X$ with at least two element. Then it is readily seen that every point $X$ is a limit point of $A$.

By intuition, I understand this statement. But I have no idea how to write the proof.

Answer (score 1):

Just definitions. Let $x \in X$ be any point. 
Let $O$ be any open set that contains $x$, then we need to show that $O \cap (A \setminus \{x\}) \neq \emptyset$.

Now, $X$ is indiscrete. So you know what $O$ has to be...

Comment: $O$ has to be X. Since $A$ contains at least two elements, then the intersection definitely contains at least one point in $A$ different than $x$.